# vue 3 vue-konva: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined

Tags: vuejs3, vue-konva

```
import VueKonva from "vue-konva";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(VueKonva, { prefix: "kv" });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Cd8.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the current moment `vue-konva` is not ready for `Vue@3` yet.

You can track the progress here:

https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva/issues/123

https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva/pull/133